# Ошибка в python 'TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable'

Tags: python

Мой код:

```
guess_me = 5
for number in int(guess_me):
    if number < guess_me:
        print('too low')
    elif number == guess_me:
        print('found it!')
        break
    elif number > guess_me:
        print('oops')
        break
```

Текст задачи:Присвойте значение 5 переменной guess_me. Используйте цикл for для того,
чтобы проитерировать с помощью переменной number по диапазону range(10).
Если значение переменной number меньше, чем значение guess_me, выведите
на экран сообщение 'too low'. Если оно равно значению guess_me — выведите
сообщение 'found it!', а затем выйдите из цикла. Если значение переменной
number больше, чем guess_me, выведите на экран сообщение 'oops' и выйдите
из цикла.

Comment: Что же вам непонятно в фразе "проитерировать с помощью переменной number по диапазону range(10)"? Замените в своём коде `int(guess_me)` на `range(10)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for number in int(guess_me):
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Замените на:

```
for number in range(10):
              ^^^^^^^^^
```

И тогда будет строго в соответствии с заданием: "проитерировать с помощью переменной `number` по диапазону `range(10)`."